# Client Policy : access denied : java.net.SocketPermission 127.0.0.1:1099

Tags: java, security, permissions, classloader, rmi

I have a strange error :

my Code :

```
System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "client.policy");
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.codebase", Servicecodebase);
System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager()); 

    Class<?> InterfaceMath =  RMIClassLoader.loadClass("http://127.0.0.1/dis/service.jar", "Service.InterfaceMath");



    Remote service = null;                  
     service  = Naming.lookup("rmi://127.0.0.1:1099/ok"); //  Error Message here
    Method getInformation = service.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("test", String.class);
    String res = (String) getInformation.invoke(service);
     System.out.println(" res : "+res);
```

My file client.policy :

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1099", "connect, resolve";
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "127.0.0.1:1099", "connect, resolve";
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:80", "connect, resolve";
};
```

my error :

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")
```

I take on Eclipse in Run Configuration - VM Arguments -Djava.security.policy==client.policy
And I lanch ---  Start rmiregistry on the console.

It's strange because I have configure my File, I load my Interface but i can't communicate with my RMI. Server  I don't know why I have this problem.

update : 
my project ClientRMI :

1. src
2. (Default package)
3. consumerTest.java
4. client.policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the file isn't being found. As you've only specified it as "client.policy", it needs to be in the current working directory when the program is launched.

If you run it with

```
-Djava.security.debug=access,failure
```

you will get a very complete trace of security manager failures, including the security domain in effect at the time and the .policy file it was configured from.

Comment: If I run only with this , and my code and mon File policy are on the same package  ( default package )

I have the Same error. acces denied ("java.net.socketPermission 127.0.0.1:1099 connect,resolve)

Comment: I don't know what 'on the same package' means, but it needs to be in the current directory when you execute the program. Packages have nothing to do with it whatsoever.

Comment: I Update my post , yes my code and my client.policy is in the current directory.

Comment: Clearly it isn't. The current working directory is the directory you're in when you execute the JAR file. It isn't the directory where the JAR file is, unless they're both the same. I suggest you trace the value of `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to see where you are really executing from. You might get a surprise. You might also attempt the security trace I mentioned in the answer. If your policy file is being found it will show up clearly there.

Comment: I try this and I have this Error : Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread")

but I have all permission

Comment: Clearly you don't. Clearly your policy file isn't being read. Clearly it isn't in the current directory, which means the current directory clearly isn't where you think it is. Clearly you haven't taken my advice to trace what it really is. Clearly you aren't taking too much notice of what you're being told here.

Comment: I Make your advice and I have : C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\JAVA\Workspace\ClientRMI
I put my client.policy in the same folder. but It's the same error , I make all information in internet but , i don't understand why I have this , sorry but I don't Have many practices on the policy file

Comment: Where is the output of -Djava.security.debug=access,failure that I asked for a day ago?Note that it is long and should be edited into your question.

Comment: I take on Eclipse in Run Configuration - VM Arguments ( Client )

Comment: I have no idea what that means, but it doesn't constitute an answer to my question, or the output when you carry out the instructions I provided. Nobody can help you if you don't answer the questions you're asked here.